# Why is this .innerHTML script not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a text link to change when clicking on it.

This is my code

```js
if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1')
  document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '2';
        else {
        document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '1';
    }
```

```html
<a id="morecat" >1</a>
```

However, it's not working, can any of you see the problem?

Comment: I've switched to a code snippet, does this still fit with the bug you encounter?

Comment: Where did you defined the function `changeText()`?

Comment: You are referencing a function that isn't defined, `changeText()`, if it actually exists you should include it as part of your question

Comment: Yes, there is a script error: "{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}"

Comment: Yes check the answer. You simply need to include your code inside the changeText() function.

Comment: I actually did it without the changetext function, also deleted it from my html in this thread. According to the result "1" is not equal to "1", and switches to the else statement wich makes it a 2.

Comment: If the inner text is `1`, it switches to `2`. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your script inside the function you assign to onClick().

```js
function changeText(){
  if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1'){
      document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '2';
   }
  else {
     document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '1';
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="morecat" onClick="changeText()" >1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in a `changeText()` method call.

```js
function changeText() {
  if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1')
    document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '2';
  else {
    document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '1';
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="morecat" onClick="changeText()">1</a>
```

Comment: I actually did it without the changetext function, also deleted it from my html in this thread. According to the result "1" is not equal to "1", and switches to the else statement wich makes it a 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write that code inside the `changeText` function like this

```js
function changeText(){
  if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1'){
      document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '2';
   }
  else {
     document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '1';
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="morecat" onClick="changeText()" >1</a>
```

Comment: no need to down vote my answer just because i answered it few seconds before you.

Comment: @AKA just an advice. If you receive downvotes on an answer, update that answer only. No need to delete and post another answer.

Comment: @AKA, I saw your rep go down from 2347 to 2346 just after the down vote to my answer.

Comment: You cannot talk blindly. Please be sure with your words.

Comment: @AKA, it was you, I am sure. Next time, show some sportsmanship. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

It works as it should:

- innerHTML of `<a id="morecat" >1</a>` is the string `1`
- given your condition : `if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1')` it set the content to the string `2`
- `2` is displayed

I've added a timer to "see" it change:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
 console.log("morecat value is " + document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML);

  if (document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML === '1'){
    document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '2';
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML = '1';
    }
 console.log("morecat value is " + document.getElementById("morecat").innerHTML);
    
 }, 3000);
```

```html
<a id="morecat">1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function named `changeText` to be used as the event listener. Besides you shouldn't make unnecessary `getElementById` calls. And for a change you may use a logical short circuit in the place of `if then else` block. Another thing to mention is to check the `textContent` property instead of `innerHTML`. Such as;

```js
function changeText(){
  var mc = document.getElementById("morecat");
  mc.textContent === "1" && (mc.textContent = "2");
}
```

```html
<a id="morecat" onClick="changeText()" >1</a>
```